# I don't live in America. How can I buy IPO stock of newly listed companies in the United States?

Tags: stocks, international, ipo, china

I'm Chinese, and I only know Firstrade, Scottrade and SogoTrade provide trading services in the Asia-Pacific region. However, they don't offer a way to buy IPO stock.

Is there any way for me to buy IPO stock? In other words, I'm looking for a broker who can offer the service of subscribing to an IPO in Asia region.

(Financial terms are a little difficult for me. Please point out if I made any mistakes or misunderstandings.)

---

I have found a useful post [here](http://www.moneyandrisk.com/retire-early/investment/how-to-get-a-hot-new-ipo-and-why-you-did-not-get-one/), which tells me that I seems have no qualifications to get in on an IPO.

Comment: Most Americans, unless they're rich aren't able to buy IPOs. If you're rich, have your banker call the banker handling the IPO and go from there. http://www.investopedia.com/university/ipo/ipo1.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to consider is that getting your hands on an IPO is very difficult unless you have some serious clout. This might help a bit in that department (http://www.sec.gov/answers/ipoelig.htm)

However, assuming you accept all that risk and requirements, YES - you can buy stocks of any kind in the US even if you are a foreigner. There are no laws prohibiting investment/buying in the US stock market. What you need is to get an online trading account from a registered brokerage house in the US. Once you are registered, you can buy whatever that is offered.

Comment: Thank you for providing me information about the IPO.Actually I know I can buy America stock in asia as mentioned in the topic,which is not I really want.As you know, IPO is different,there can be a large difference between the price of shares when purchased in an IPO and the price for the same shares when they start trading in the secondary market.But the service brokers provide for me just can buy American shares have been listed, which do not contain subscribing IPO.

Comment: In short, I'm looking for a broker can offer service of subscribing IPO to asia region.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I posted the IPO information first. IPOs are offered in bulk or wholesale if you will to a very limited number of very large brokerage houses and funds. Some of these will set aside some of their shares to sell to the public, but even then have very high limit (meaning cash in the account/portfolio) to even offer then. So for all intents and purposes unless you are a large corporation with massive accounts, getting an IPO is not realistic, that's what I was trying to get across.

Comment: That being said, I didn't know how much money you have to work with and I didn't want to presume, that's why I said if you have a brokerage account and they have any available IPOs mentioned earlier earmarked for the public, then you can try to get some if you meet their requirements. Also, keep in mind that you often don't want to be investing in the IPO anyway, you want to wait a bit. For example, take Facebook, if you did IPO you paid $45/share but if you waited, you could have gotten a ton of it at lower price 6 months later and by now due to the rebound, worth a lot more. It's timing.

Comment: @Mithril Original IPO shares are not usually available unless you had something to do with the company before IPO or you know someone involved in it. What you are looking for in the securities equivalent of a unicorn dealer. There aren't any.